# How helm2 uses the semverCompare function similar to helm3

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a project deployed using **helm2**, but with the upgrade of the k8s version, the `apiVersion` of `rbac` has changed. However, not all k8s clusters are upgraded together, so they need to be *compatible* with different versions.

I searched for [information](https://github.com/julor/seaweedfs/blob/179039afaaa9abacc5dde635dd26ea12f0888828/k8s/charts/seaweedfs/templates/s3-ingress.yaml#L2C1-L6C12) and found that I can use Helm's `semverCompare` function.

I modified the apiVersion of the `Role` resource through the reference.

```yaml
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.22-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion }}
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
{{- else }}
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Role
...
...
```

But semverCompare seems to be a function of [Helm3 semvercompare](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#semvercompare).  I didn't find any description of this function in [helm2](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/).

I would like to ask if there is a function similar to `semvercompare` in helm2, or to implement the function of semvercompare in other ways. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Just to clarify, have you tried using it in v2 and it doesn't work, or are you concerned that it is not present in documentation for v2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listing of template functions in the Helm documentation is somewhat recent.  Older versions of the [documentation](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#template-functions-and-pipelines) contain text like this:

> Helm has over 60 available functions. Some of them are defined by the [Go template language](https://godoc.org/text/template) itself. Most of the others are part of the [Sprig template library](https://godoc.org/github.com/Masterminds/sprig). We’ll see many of them as we progress through the examples.

And, indeed, the [semantic version functions](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/semver.html) are part of Sprig.

The next question is, does this very old version of Helm contain these functions?  The [Helm 2.17 source](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/v2.17.0/glide.yaml#L21-L22) references Sprig 2.20.0.  That version of Sprig does seem to contain the [semver functions](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/v2.20.0/semver.go).  So you're probably good to use these, even on a 4-year-old unmaintained version of the Helm tool.

Helm (including [this old version](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#built-in-objects)) also has a `.Capabilities` object which lets you check what API versions the cluster supports.  Rather than gating on the Kubernetes version, it may be easier to just ask if the newer API version exists

```yaml
{{- if .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1" }}
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
{{- else }}
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Role
```